# How do I write an MSpec test for user permissions in a special folder?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, user-permissions, mspec

I have a portable application updater. We check that the logged-in user has write access to the working directory before updating the application. Does anyone know how to write a test that asserts those privileges?

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
try
{
    var security = FolderAndFiles
       .WorkingDirectory
       .GetAccessControl()
       .GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof (NTAccount));
}
catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    // throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I have handled this is to create an abstraction of the filesystem that contains just the facilities I need. In this example, I was creating a utility to extract information from a Git log history. I made all the methods virtual so they can be mocked, but you could just as easily define an interface.

```
/// <summary>
///   Class FileSystemService - an abstraction over file system services.
///   This class consists mainly of virtual methods and exists primarily to aid testability.
/// </summary>
public class FileSystemService
    {
    public virtual bool DirectoryExists(string path)
        {
        return Directory.Exists(path);
        }

    public virtual string PathCombine(string path1, string path2)
        {
        return Path.Combine(path1, path2);
        }

    public virtual string GetFullPath(string path)
        {
        return Path.GetFullPath(path);
        }

    public virtual void SaveImage(string path, Bitmap image, ImageFormat format)
        {
        image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Having created the filesystem service, inject it into any object that needs it like so:

```
class SomeClassThatNeedsTheFileSystem
    {
    public SomeClassThatNeedsTheFileSystem(FileSystemService filesystem = null)
        {
        fileSystem = filesystem ?? new FileSystemService();
        }
    }
```

Note: this was a rather small project and I didn't want to get involved with IoC containers, so I did "poor man's IoC" by making the FileSystemService an optional parameter with a default value of 'null'; I then test for null and new up a FileSystemService within the constructor. Ideally, for more robust code, I would make the parameter mandatory and force the caller to pass in a FileSystemService.

When it comes time to create a fake, I do it like this (I'm using MSpec and FakeItEasy):

```
// Some stuff elided for clarity
public class with_fake_filesystem_service
    {
    Establish context = () =>
        {
        Filesystem = A.Fake<FileSystemService>();
        };

    protected static FileSystemService Filesystem;
    }
```